Collision Operators (Boltzmann Equation)
I have been reading lately about cosmology and more specifically the freeze-out of different particles. I stumbled a lot on the Boltzmann equation, which as I understand describes how distribution functions change (mostly the number density of particles). This equations has a part that describes the contribution to the change from the interactions, the so called collision operator.
From what I have read, the collision term is the integral over the phase space of the Matrix element squared. Let's say we have a $2\rightarrow2$ interaction that would be something like
$$C=\int \prod\limits_{i=1}^4\frac{d^3p_i}{(2\pi)^3 2E_i}f_1f_2(1\pm f_3)(1\pm f_4)|M_{12\to 34}|^2,$$
where $f_i$ are the distribution function of the particle populations.
To me this seems a lot like some kind of interaction rate, but for this particular case this has units of energy to the fourth (which is not compatible to $1/s$ or energy which we would expect from a rate). So my question is if the collision operator is at all related to the decay rate (as calculated let's say from Fermi's Golden Rule)?
Also if someone could provide some literature on the subject it would be greatly appreciated because I've only found papers that discuss this.
